# Spring - Multiple PathVariable values for generic request mapping handler

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm trying to implement a hierarchical taxonomy tree, where it follows the structure

```
                                    term 1
                                    /    \
                                term 2  term 3
                                       /   |   \
                                 term 4 term 5  term 6
```

where each `Term` object contains a set containing all the `Term`s below it.

Traditionally, to access the third level of terms, with a url

```
/term/chapter/section/paragraph
```

a Spring `RequestMapping` would consist of

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/term/{term1}/{term2}/{term3}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Term getTerm(@PathVariable("term1") Term rootTerm, 
                    @PathVariable("term2") Term childTerm,
                    @PathVariable("term3") Term leafTerm) {

  /* Processing code here */

  return Term;

}
```

The downside for this is that it specifically limits the height of the taxonomy tree to the number of specified handlers for the requested URLs.  In this case, I'm limited to a tree of height 3.

Is there a built in way to pass in the extra `Term` URL identifiers to a method with no regard to number of child `Term`s?  Or would I have to work on processing the URL itself within the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use one parameter with parsing.

Instead of specifying a url like this:

`/term/depth1/depth2/.../dephtN`

You could specify a format convention and query your term like this:

`/term/depth1-depth2-...-depthN`

In your controller you can then parse the URL:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/term/{query}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Term getTerm(@PathVariable String query) {

    // example access
    String[] parts = query.split("-");
    String chapterId = parts[0];
    String sectionId = parts[1];
    String paragraphId = parts[2];
    // ... to be continued

    /* Processing code here */

  return Term;
}
```

Comment: That would work, from a logged in admin user perspective.  However, this would not work from an API perspective, as fetching this data should be via a GET request and be URL-dependent only

Comment: @Jason - Okay, I changed my answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do that with path variables. Path variables are nice in REST URLs, provided the systax of the URL be constant, and you want it to be extensible to any number of terms.

IMHO you have to fall back to request parameters to that. But fortunately, Spring MVC is kind enough to automatically convert indexed parameters to a List. You could do :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/term", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Term getTerm(@ModelAttribute TermPath termPath) {
//code
}
```

with

```
class TermPath {
    List<String> path;

    Term getTerm() { // extract the Term corresponding to the path
    ...
    }
    // getter and setter
}
```

and use URLs like : `/term?path[0]=chapter&path[1]=section&path[2]=paragraph...`